# Identify a movie from the 80s: desert, water sirens

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

I'm looking for a movie that I saw as a child in the 80s. It was a post-apocalyptic world with a group of survivors. They were in a deserted area. Once they entered a tunnel where the floor was covered in water. And here water amazons / sirens appeared that tried to drag them down. Could you help me identify this movie?

Edit: I think it was an American movie. The group entered the tunnel in a Mad Max-like car. If I remember correctly, there was an African-American guy also in the group. The set was deserted / rocky.

Comment: Welcome to the site, if you have more details on the film it would be helpful (was the movie in English, you saw it in the 80s but was it made in 80s, etc). Check out our meta post on [How to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Thanks. I added some more info to the question.

Comment: So, did the sirens seem magical? Mutants? Normal people in costumes? Aliens? Aliens.

Comment: The sirens were pretty women in mad max-like costumes, not aliens. The group managed to escape from the tunnel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That sounds like *Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone*.  A 3D science fiction movie from 1983 that takes place on a desert planet.  It starred Molly Ringwald, Peter Strauss, and Michael Ironside.  About 42 minutes into the movie, Strauss and Ringwald drive a futuristic vehicle through a water filled tunnel.  They are attacked from under the water by a group of women who want to pull them under, but they escape.

Three Earth women crash on a desert planet.  Strauss plays a Solo-type rogue who is trying to rescue them for a big payout.  Ironside plays an evil half-man, half-machine who rules the planet.  He also wants the Earth women.  Strauss meets a local girl (Ringwald) who tags along and becomes his sidekick.

Comment: Thank you, that's it!